# How to remove duplicate row but save the latest one (VBA)?

Tags: excel, duplicates, addition

I have an excel where I have 2 sheets and I want to import selected columns to another sheet and delete possible duplicate rows. The problem is, that when I run my code, it deletes my latest duplicate row, eventhough I want to save latest row and delete the other 'older' duplicate. I really appreciate any help! Thank you :) Here is my code what I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("one").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 1).Copy
erow = Worksheets("two").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("two").Cells(erow + 1, 1)

Worksheets("one").Cells(i, 3).Copy
Worksheets("one").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("two").Cells(erow + 1, 2)

Next i

End Sub
```

Another question is, I have tried this code for test excel, but where I want to use this macro has a lot larger data. It takes a very long time to go through all the data.. is the problem in my code or is the actual excel just so big? I hope I explain everything crearly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> "The problem is, that when I run my code, it deletes my latest duplicate row..."

The problem is the sort order of your data.

`Remove Duplicates` moves from first index to last and and keeps the first occurrence.  So you either need to sort your data such that your "oldest" duplicate is the first occurrence at top or you have to use a different method to remove duplicates.

---

> "is the problem in my code or is the actual excel just so big?"

It could be both, but one thing is certain, your code can definitely run faster.

The low hanging fruit is to put `Application.EnableScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning of you sub. That stops Excel from updating the screen when your runs.  It will make a huge difference.  Just remember to set it back to `True` again.

You're also looping through a range one row at a time but I don't see any particular reason why you need to.  You can copy the while range in a single statement without looping.   You don't even need to copy of you don't care about ordering the format, you could transfer the values just make the ranges equal each other.

An example of how you to transfer values without cutting or looping

```
  Worksheets("two").Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Value = Worksheets("one").Range("E2:E" & lastrow).Value
```

You can use the same approach with copy and paste if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I wil try again :)